# Remove keypoints and descriptors inside an area

Tags: python, opencv

I have a script in which I try to detect multiple objects inside an image. I use opencv 2.4

When I detect an object, I remove the area occupied by that object in the image (paint that area in black) and recalculate the kp and des. This takes a lot of time because I need to paint over the image and recalculate all.

Is it possible to remove those keypoints from the list of keypoints? This would save lot of time.

I have the coordinates of the area. I don't know how to get the coordinates of each point and each descriptor.

Comment: [Keypoint](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/features2d/KeyPoint.html) has an object with the coordinates of the keypoint

Comment: Thank you. What's about descriptors? I do not see the class entry on the documentation.

Comment: The descriptors are saved as MatOf[DMatch](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/features2d/DMatch.html) which have queryIdx and trainIdx, corresponding to keypoint id in the two images.

Comment: Does this solve your problem?

Comment: If you know the area that you do not want to detect using keypoints, you should consider **masking** that portion of the image